# How to search something in mysql by searching a part of it

Tags: python, mysql

Let's say we have this query:

```
query = "SELECT surname FROM set_payment WHERE surname = %s"
mycursor.execute(query,("Smith",))
```

If we have the surname 'Smith' for example in our table it should print Smith. Is there a way to search for something by searching a part of it? For example, if a search for Sm to print all surnames that contain the letters 'Sm'?

Comment: Sounds like you need the [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [LIKE operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) using %.
example:
`WHERE surname LIKE '%sm%'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is possible.

You can use "where" with "like" in MySQL query.

For your search you can write the query like this:

WHERE surname LIKE '%sm%';

this searches all names that contains 'sm'.